# express-hbs instance registerAsyncHelper weird hash

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using express-hbs nodejs module and I have an issue using `registerAsyncHelper`.  I need compile a layout in restrict scope because of this I've created a new Handlebars instance and I've created a helper in this instance. But when I compile the layout it returns a weird hash.
My code is something like this:

```
var hbs = require('express-hbs');
var hbs_temp = hbs.create();

hbs_temp.registerAsyncHelper( 'content', function( text, cb ) {     
    fs.readFile( 'some-file', { encoding: 'utf8' }, function( err, data ) {
        cb( new hbs_temp.SafeString( data ) );
    });
});

hbs_temp.compile( '<div> {{content}} </div>' )(  );`
```

Result:

`<div> __WEIRD HASH__ </div>`

My question is. I've something wrong in my code or this is a "express-hbs" bug?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The express-hbs module inserts those hashes in place of asynchronously returned values, and replaces them when the async calls have completed.  You must use it in the context of Express, as a rendering engine to see this working.

Comment: Thank you skieter. In this case I need two handlerbar contexts. The best option may be to create two extensions files otherwise I can't have two contexts and use asynchronous helpers.

Comment: It may be best to use handlebars directly, first getting the async-loaded content and then sending these values to handlebars.